# Prevent page reload on form Button click in meteor?

Tags: javascript, html, http, meteor

Not sure whether this is a Meteor problem, JavaScript problem, or otherwise. Clicking on a form button causes an undesired page reload.

**Other info:**

- Using Bootstrap package
- Using jQuery package
- Using Backbone package
- Page-reload problem still happens even when above packages are removed
- Commenting out the Posts.insert() line doesn't fix it either

  // from application.js
  // *this is the only event related code in the app (*aside from any behind-the-scenes stuff abstracted away from us by meteor*)

  ```
  Template.new_post.events = { 

      'click #submit' : function () {

        var text = $('#title').val();
        var cat = $('#category').val();

        // save our post with the value of the textbox
        Posts.insert({title : text, category : cat});
      }
  };
  ```

  // from index.html

  ```
  <template name="new_post">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
      <fieldset>
      <div class="control-group">
        <!-- Text input-->
        <label class="control-label" for="title">Title</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="text" id="title" value="{{text}}" class="input-xlarge">
          <p class="help-block">Hint: Summarize your post in a few words</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="form-part-2">
        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="categories">Category</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <select class="input-xlarge" id="category">
              {{#each categories}}
                <option value="{{defaultLabel}}">{{defaultLabel}}</option>
              {{/each}}
            </select>
            <p class="help-block">Hint: Choose a category</p>
          </div>
        </div>
          <!-- Button -->
          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
              <button class="btn btn-success" id="submit">Done</button>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div><!-- end div form-part-2 -->
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </template>
  ```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you have to return false at the end of your function for prevent submit.

Comment: I just ran into this problem, as well.
Thanks!

Comment: return false does not seem to work for me in Meteor 1.0 with Firefox 33.

Comment: No you should not use return false. you should always use `event.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 5):

Other than returning `false` you can also call `preventDefault()` on the [event passed into your handler](http://docs.meteor.com/#eventmaps):

```
'click #submit' : function (template, event) {
  ...
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

This will only prevent the default action (i.e. submitting the form), but will not stop the event from propagating.

Comment: event.preventDefault() doesnt work on firefox http://stackoverflow.com/q/18464913/522050

Comment: If this method works for you, you can put it at the beginning so any errors further on won't result in the page refreshing.